# Dynamic chart title from userform

Tags: excel, vba, charts, userform

I am attempting to label a Dynamic Chart from a Userform. Although I receive no errors from the following code, I still do not get any title on the chart?!?

```
 With Worksheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects(1).Chart
.HasTitle = True
.ChartTitle.Text = "Comparisons"
 End With
```

Please, why is this? How can I remedy the situation?
Thank you!

Comment: Do you have anything in the chart?  I found that the title doesn't show up until you have some values in the chart.  It does, however, save the title and then once you put the values in there, it shows up correctly.

Comment: Nothing was in there. There is now, and there is a title. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to have values in the chart for the title to display.

The code will title, with the desired text, and will display as soon as you put values in the chart.